# NoReverseMatch at /account/login/

Tags: django-2.2

I'm trying to figure out Django default auth and when I log in with correct credentials it give me this error

```
NoReverseMatch at /account/login/
Reverse for 'dashboard' not found. 'dashboard' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/account/login/
Django Version: 2.2
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'dashboard' not found. 'dashboard' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
Exception Location: C:\Users\nouma\Desktop\social_website\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py in _reverse_with_prefix, line 660
```

I've seen some similar problems but couldn't understand what exactly my problem is. I'm confused with the concept of **reverse not found**.
Here's my **views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from .forms import LoginForm
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
# Create your views here.

def user_login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            user = authenticate(request, username=cd['username'], password=cd['password'])

            if user is not None:
                if user.is_active:
                    login(request, user)
                    return HttpResponse('Authenticated successfully')
                else:
                    return HttpResponse('Disabled account')
            else:
                return HttpResponse('Invalid login')
    else:
        form = LoginForm()
    return render(request, 'account/login.html', {'form': form})

@login_required
def dashboard(request):
    return render(request, 'account/dashboard.html', {'section': 'dashboard'})
```

here's my main **urls.py** of the project

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('account/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('account/', include('account.urls', namespace='account')),
]
```

**urls.py** of app named **account**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

app_name = 'account'

urlpatterns = [
    # login view
    # path('login/', views.user_login, name='user_login'),

    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
    path('', views.dashboard, name='dashboard'),
]
```

My **dasboard.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}Dashboard{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
  <h1>Dashboard</h1>
  <p>Welcome to your dashboard</p>
{% endblock %}
```

**login.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %}Log-in{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
  <h1>Log-in</h1>
  {% if form.errors %}
    <p>Your username or password didn't match. Please try again</p>
  {% else %}
    <p>Please, use the following form to log-in:</p>
  {% endif %}
  <div class="login-form">
    <form action="{% url 'login' %}" method="POST">
      {{ form.as_p }}
      {% csrf_token %}
      <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
      <p><input type="submit" value="Log-in"></p>
    </form>
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

I think the problem is minor but I'm unable to configure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have created a custom application `account` for which you do not have defined url in the `app/urls.py` file.

You can add account urls like

```
urlpatterns = [
  path('account/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
  path('account/', include('account.urls', namespace='account'))
]
```

Now you can create reverse urls for the urls defined in the `account` app.

> Edit 2

Also since you have defined the `django.contrib.auth` views in the `account/urls.py` file, you do not need to add the url for `django.contrib.auth.urls` in the `app/urls.py` file.

> LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL

As per the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#login-redirect-url), It accepts `path` or `named` url pattern.

The suggest way is the use of `path`. For `named` usages you may try with the following

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'account:login'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = reverse('account:login')
```

I'm not sure which one of the above will work, let me know which one worked for you.

Comment: I have tried both of these edits but I'm having same error

Comment: Can you share where have you used the reverse for `dashboard`?

Comment: Plus if I remove the `include('django.contrib.auth.urls')` I'm having another error so I'm keeping both path as you have mentioned. But for now my problem is same even after using both. Please look into it if you can.

Comment: If I'm getting it right its at the end of my provided views.py file as
`@login_required
def dashboard(request):
    return render(request, 'account/dashboard.html', {'section': 'dashboard'})`

Comment: I'm not talking about the definition. I'm talking about it's usages. Do you have `{% url 'dashboard' %}` or `reverse('dashboard')` somewhere in you app?

Comment: No. I'm using it to redirect successful login. It's in my settings.py file as `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'dashboard'`

Comment: plus the redirection is done by the `{{ next }}` tag (if I'm not wrong). I have added the `login.html` file in question.

Comment: For that you can use `LOGIN_REDIRECt_URL = '/account'`

Comment: That worked! thank you and could you please tell me why didn't `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'dashboard'` work since I have `name='dashboard'` in the path for dashboard as `path('', views.dashboard, name='dashboard')`

Comment: Updated answer. Please check and let me know if it works for you